# circular shift left of indexes - verilog

Tags: indexing, verilog, shift

I want to connect two modules so that
 output_module1[i] --> input_module2[circular_shift_left(i)]

for example :

```
output_module1[100] --> input_module2[001] // (output no. 5 to input no. 2)

output_module1[011] --> input_module2[110] // (output no. 4 to input no. 7)
```

the length of both modules is generic.

what's the most efficient (and easiest) way to implement it in verilog?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried already?

Comment: Is the width of `output_module1` a power of two? Otherwise, it's not guaranteed that both `i` and `circular_shift_left(i)` are within the vector.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the easiest way to make a circular shift would be to combine the part select and concatenation operators.

```
wire [7:0] in;
wire [7:0] out;

assign out = {in[6:0], in[7]};
```